# Django Aggregation in Model

Tags: django, aggregation

Hi I'm coding a site that uses donations as multiple items on a Project.
I'm calculating the total amount of donations, but it doesn't seem to work. Do i need an intermediate table between the two models?

I was wondering if there's a better to way to do it with Django Aggregation.

```
class Donation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    amount= models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    donations=models.ManyToManyField(Donation, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def progress(self):
        donations = self.donations.all()
        total_donations = 0
        for item in donations:
            total_donations += item.amount
        return total_donations
```

Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: You should write down code that you've already tried. It would give us a better idea of what you're after.

Comment: Will a single donation ever go to multiple projects?  If not, you probably don't want a many to many field.  You can put a foreign key field in Donation to Project instead.

Comment: Bryce, thanks for your response. I'm trying the code as we speak, with no results :S

Comment: Marc, you are right. A Donation will never go to multiple projects but a Project can have many donations.

Comment: I was trying to do it from the Project model to speed the lookup... by using  Project.progress on my templates..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd get rid of the `progess` method and simply annotate the queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Project.objects.annotate(progress=Sum('donations__amount'))
```

You could even use a custom `Manager`:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class ProjectManager(models.Manager):
    def all_with_progress(self):
        return self.get_query_set().annotate(progress=Sum('donations__amount'))

class Project(models.Model)
    ...
    objects = ProjectManager()
```

Then:

```
>>> projects = Project.objects.all_with_progress()
>>> projects[0].progress
700
```

Or you could even override the default queryset so progress is always returned:

```
class ProjectManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(ProjectManager, self).get_query_set(*args, **kwargs)
        return qs.annotate(progress=Sum('donations__amount'))
```

Then:

```
>>> projects = Project.objects.all()
>>> projects[0].progress
700
```

Comment: Going this route would be the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
def progress(self):
    from django.db.models import Sum
    amount = self.donations.exclude(amount=None).aggregate(progress=Sum('amount'))['progress']
    if amount:
        return amount
    return 0
```

I think that'll give you what you want. You'll have to play with it a bit, and let me know if you have any problems. Also, make sure you version of Django supports aggregation.

EDIT: Fixed a problem where none was being returned.

Comment: This seems to be the solution... but i keep getting "None" in the return value

Comment: Are there any donations with amounts connected to that Project?

Comment: Yep, i'm testing the Project with 2 donations (items) added

Comment: Try the new code I just added... maybe it'll give better results

Comment: I have two Donation objects added to the Donations ManytoMany field. One with "200.00" and the other with "500.00". But i'm still getting 0.

I'm usign DecimalField for the amount field in Donation.

Thanks for your quick responses!

Comment: Can you try printing off what this returns: self.donations.exclude(amount=None) ? I'm thinking that it might not be returning the expected queryset

Comment: When i print self.donations.exclude(amount=None) it shows []. When printing self.donations it shows <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager ...>

Comment: Try removing the .exclude(...) portion and just have self.donations.aggregate(...)

Comment: When would a donation amount be `None`? It's a required field and is not null-able. It would always have to be some number, even if that number is simply `0`.

Comment: Yea, that's what I thought too, but the Sum() aggregate was returning None so I thought maybe he had a None value in there somewhere.

Comment: Sum() would only return `None` if there are no donations for a project. That case should simply be handled in the code, for example: `if progress == None: progress = 0`

Comment: But he was planning on using it in the template so he wont' be able to handle it in the code. Well... I mean he can, but it would be quite unnecessary.

Comment: Well, you could still use something like: `{% if progress %}{{ progress }}{% else %}0{% endif %}` or more compactly, `{{ progress|default:"0" }}`